# PHP Hangman application Right to Left

Tags: php

I need to write hangman game, when you guess letters, in Hebrew.
All is working fine but when I'm guessing the word.
Means first letter is Right but second letter appears not to the left of it but to the right of it, Example:

A ->  AB
and I need it to be
A ->  BA

code is very long since I'm not allowed to use any loops (I know it's stupid).
Here is a link to the main page of the application: http://pastebin.com/tmaUFLGi

I've tried using strrev, no success there.

Thanks for any help given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using html5 to render it from right to left? While you can juggle with your variables without having to transform them. What if you need to show the application in English? You just use some css, simple as that.

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_bdo_dir.asp

Comment: If I declare dir="rtl" in the html tag, shouldn't it work also?

Comment: This is exactly the type of situations for which bdo was intended for. Now i see what you meant, yes it will work, but I'm sure using bdo will give you some extra credit :)

Comment: well bdo worked while dir-"rtl" on html tag simply ruined the app. Thank you!